# Having 2 Initialize Paragraphs in 1 COBOL program

Tags: sql, cobol

I am designing a COBOL program that does 2 things.
1 reads specific rows from a table, and inserts a new row based on the original.
2 reads different rows from the same table, and updates those rows.

Is it bad standards to have 2 initialization procedures? I need to declare 2 SQL cursors, one for each task. So I was thinking:
`1 initialize cursor, 2 process, 3 initialize cursor, 4 process.`

But that seems like bad logic. something is telling me it should be more like:
`1 initialize cursor, 2 process` But I'm having trouble thinking it out because to me, they are 2 separate tasks.

I tried to think of a way that my SQL query could do the work, and then I could just do some validation. But I'm not sure the query would be any more efficient than having a second read of the table.

[Here's my structure ideas](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1q4X8fu4HDLsZZ_emCFFNjl6TL-3W5wNw1-VjzxU_Y1c/edit)
I've added a 3rd chart that I believe follows the answer given to me on this question. Does the 3rd chart seem to me the most logical?

Comment: Designing a COBOL program, as in writing new COBOL, not merely maintaining it?  Poor you... :(

Comment: I disagree. New code > maintenance.

Comment: New code becomes -> maintenance code. Why prolong the suffering??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should separate the two tasks. You should have two cursors and initialize each separately since one is used for read and the other is for read/write.

You'd go like:

```
 Move 0 to rc.
 
 Perform Task1
 
 If rc > 0
 
           logic to display message and end run.
 
 end
 
 perform Task2
 
 If rc > 0
 
           logic to display message and end run.
 
 end
 
 perform end of job messages and close open files if any.
 
 Stop Run. 

.....................
 
 Task1 is:
 
 Open cursor 1 ... 

... 

Close cursor 1. 

.....................

 
 Task2 is:
 

 Open cursor 2 ... 

... 

Close cursor 2.
```

Answer (score 4):

In outline it sh:ould look like:

```
    A01-MAIN
        PEFFORM B01-PROCESS-CURSOR1
        IF OK
           PERFORM C01-PROCESS-CURSOR2
        END-IF

    B01-PROCESS-CURSOR1.
        PERFORM B02-INITIAL.
        PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE NOT = 0
           PERFORM B03-NEXT-ROW
           PERFORM B04-INSERT-NEW
        END-PERFORM.
        PERFORM B09-CLOSE.

    .
    .
    .
    C01-PROCESS-CURSOR2.
        PERFORM C02-INITIAL.
        PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE NOT = 0
           PERFORM C03-NEXT-ROW
           PERFORM C04-UPDATE
        END-PERFORM.
        PERFORM C09-CLOSE.

    .
```